# What can I do with virtual classes?

Tags: scala

I've seen (and heard) quite a bit of noise about adding *virtual classes* to Scala (it already has *[virtual types](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/IC_TECH_REPORT_2005013.pdf#)*, according to [Martin Odersky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Odersky)).

What is a layman's perspective (perhaps with an example) on what a virtual type is and **what could be possible** were Scala to have virtual classes?

(*[I have no experience with C or C++, so would prefer any answer not to refer to these languages]*.)

Comment: The Scala eclipse plugin used to be implemented using virtual classes.  Are we talking about the same thing? http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/wiki/VirtualClasses

Comment: I don't know! That's why I asked the question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Virtual types are simple:

- Classes and traits can have type members. E.g.

  ```
  trait Foo {
    type T
  }
  ```
- They can be refined (but not overridden once defined):

  ```
  class Foo1 extends Foo {
    type T <: AnyVal
  }

  class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
    override type T = Boolean
  }

  class Foo3 extends Foo2 {
    // override type T = Int // rejected by the compiler – would be unsound
  }
  ```

Here is [an example of virtual classes in a Java-descendent language](http://caesarj.org/index.php/ProgrammingGuide/VirtualClasses) (`cclass` is a virtual class):

> **Features of Virtual Classes**
>
> Let's look
>   to another example to study the
>   possibilities of virtual classes. We
>   will use virtual classes to extend a
>   collaboration with a totally new
>   funtionality. Let’s say we have a core
>   data model to represent expressions:
>
> ```
> public cclass ExprModel {
>    abstract public cclass Expr {}
>
>    public cclass Constant extends Expr {
>       protected int _val;
>       public Constant(int val) { 
>          _val = val;
>       }                 
>    }
>
>    abstract public cclass BinaryExpr {
>       protected Expr _left;
>       protected Expr _right;
>       public BinaryExpr(Expr left, Expr right) {
>          _left = left;
>          _right = right;
>       }
>    }
>
>    public cclass Add extends BinaryExpr {}
>    public cclass Mult extends BinaryExpr {} 
> }
> ```
>
> The collaboration defines Expr as the
>   base class for all expressions,
>   concrete classes to represent
>   constants, addition and
>   multiplication. Class BinaryExpr
>   implements the common functionality of
>   all expressions with two operands.
>   Note that the current version of
>   Caesar does not support constructors
>   with parameters and abstract methods
>   in cclass. The code below demonstrates
>   how sample expressions can be built
>   using such collaboration:
>
> ```
> public model.Expr buildSampleExpr(final ExprModel model) {
>    model.Expr const1 = model.new Constant(-3);
>    model.Expr const2 = model.new Constant(2);
>    model.Expr op1 = model.new Mult(const1, const2);
>    model.Expr const3 = model.new Constant(5);
>    model.Expr op2 = model.new Add(op1, const3);
>    return op2;
> }
> ```
>
> The collaboration defines Expr as the
>   base class for all expressions,
>   concrete classes to represent
>   constants, addition and
>   multiplication. Class BinaryExpr
>   implements the common functionality of
>   all expressions with two operands.
>
> There are a lot of different
>   functionality related with
>   expressions: their evaluation,
>   formatting expressions to simple text
>   in infix or postfix order, various
>   consistency checks, lookups and
>   transformations. We want to keep all
>   this specific functionality separated
>   from each other and from the core data
>   model. This can be achieved with the
>   help of virtual classes. For example,
>   the collaboration below extends the
>   core model with simple expression
>   formatting functionality:
>
> ```
> public cclass ExprFormat extends ExprModel {
>    abstract public cclass Expr {       
>       abstract public void String format();
>    }
>
>    public cclass Constant {
>       public void String format() { 
>          return _val < 0 ? “(“ + _val + “)” : “” + _val; 
>       }
>    }
>
>    abstract public cclass BinaryExpr {
>       public void String format() { 
>          return “(” + _left.format() + getOperSymbol() 
>                     + _right.format() + “)”; 
>       }
>       abstract public void String getOperSymbol();
>    }
>
>    public cclass Add {
>       public void String getOperSymbol() { return “+”; }
>    }
>
>    public cclass Mult {
>       public void String getOperSymbol() { return “*”; }
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> This short example demonstrates
>   various features of virtual classes:
>
> - There is no need to repeat inheritance relationships between
>     virtual classes if they are already
>     defined in the supercollaboration. For
>     example ExprModel defines Constant as
>     subclass of Expr. It means that
>     Constant is implicitly assumed as
>     subclass of Expr in ExprFormat as
>     well.
> - Virtual classes can use the fields and methods defined in their
>     older versions. For example
>     ExprFormat.BinaryExpr can use fields
>     _left and _right defined in ExprModel.BinaryExpr.
> - The functionality defined in the overridden virtual classes can be
>     accessed without type casts. For
>     example, fields _left and _right of
>     BinaryExpr were initially declared
>     with type Expr of ExprModel, which
>     does not have method format(), but in
>     the context of ExprFormat the new
>     version of Expr is assumed as the type
>     of _left and _right. So format() can
>     be called without any type casts.
> - The methods introduced in the overridden virtual classes can be
>     again overridden in the new versions
>     of subclasses. For example overridden
>     Expr introduces method format(), which
>     can be overridden in BinaryExpr. While
>     Add and Mult do not override this
>     method further, they inherit the
>     format() of BinaryExpr.
>
> Besides the demonstrated properties,
>   the overridden virtual classes can
>   also
>
> - introduce new data fields,
> - implement new interfaces,
> - introduce new inheritance relationships.

Comment: your first example doesn't compile: scala> class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
     |   override type T = Boolean
     | }
<console>:10: error: overriding type T in class Foo1, which equals Int;
 type T has incompatible type
         override type T = Boolean
                       ^

Comment: `override type T = Boolean`? That won't compile. (Just noticed Oleg said the same thing above.)