# Override a class inside of a class

Tags: scala

Given `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  def getBar = new Bar

  class Bar {
    def baz = 3
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to extend `Foo`, and override `baz`.
The simplest implementation I can think of is this:

```
class Foo2 extends Foo {
  override def getBar = new Bar2

  class Bar2 extends Bar {
    override def baz = 5
  }
}
```

but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve this. 
(`getBar` might contain a lot of code, and I don't won't to copy paste it with just a small change `Bar` -> `Bar2`)

I tried this:

```
class Foo2 {

  class Bar extends super.Bar {
    override def baz = 5
  }
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work
(`new Foo2().getBar.baz == 3`)

Any other ideas?

Update:
fixed compilation error as mentioned in the responses

Comment: Why aren't you using the `override` modifier?

Comment: It does help if the code you provide in your question compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding classes requires something like [virtual classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035807/what-can-i-do-with-virtual-classes). But they don't exist, so that is impossible.

I would advise not to do `class Bar extends super.Bar`, because then you're just shadowing the `Bar` class from `Foo`, which will only cause confusion. I think the best you can do is provide a method in `Foo` that constructs a `Bar`, as an alias for the real constructor. Because methods can be overridden, constructors can't.

```
class Foo {
  final def getBar = {
    val i: Int = doLotsOfComputations1()
    val s: String = doLotsOfComputations2()
    initBar(i, s)
  }

  protected def initBar(i: Int, s: String): Bar = new Bar(i, s)

  protected class Bar(i: Int, s: String) {
    def baz = 3
  }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
  override protected def initBar(i: Int, s: String) = new Bar2(i, s)

  protected class Bar2(i: Int, s: String) extends Bar(i, s) {
    override def baz = 5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing override

```
  class Foo {
def getBar = new Bar

class Bar {
  def baz = 3
}}

  class Foo2 extends Foo {
override def getBar = new Bar2

class Bar2 extends Bar {
  override def baz = 5
}}
```